# Best search algorithm in large array of objects with several fields

Tags: javascript, ruby, algorithm, search

I have a large array of objects **~10000** in memory (not in db). Object has five fields: **id**, **type**, **status**, **dateFrom** and **dateTo**. Field **type** has ~5 unique values, field **status** has ~5 unique values, **dateFrom** and **dateTo** may have different unique values.

Instead of use brute force search first thought was to build index by each field. For **type** and **status** we can group objects by each field, ok. For **dateTo** and **dateFrom** we can use kd-tree, ok.

Is this search strategy good enough? How I can merge the result of different indexes? Have any ideas?

Comment: can you show one instance(element) from that array?

Comment: What is your end goal? Since you are looking to index the data I assume searching? Which fields will be searched? Is the data sorted in any way (Searching sorted data can be much faster than indexing)?

Comment: @marmeladze `{ id: 1, status: 4, type: 3, dateFrom: %timestamp%, dateTo: %timestamp% }`

Comment: The index for field is a good solution, but can be memory eater. Looping on more than 10000 and test if value is inside the object will be very slow

Comment: @William_Wilson the goal is effective searching by fields: **type**, **status**, **dateFrom**, **dateTo**. Set of fields can be from one to all (4).

Comment: @poporul your data is atomic.  you can just divide your array of hashes into smaller parts (e.g. you have an array of 10000 records, divide it array of 100 hashes (according to type, status or timestamps), then you'll have 100 arrays with some unique (or) mutual attributes)
have a look up, algebra of hashing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function#Minimal_perfect_hash_function

Comment: Hmm, if a multi-field search is required then some form of indexing is a good idea, but as romuleald mentioned it will hog quite a bit of memory. Is there any requirement of fields supplied? E.g. can the use supply any of the 4 fields or if they supply 1 field is it always type?

Comment: @marmeladze as I understood this approach will work if all attributes presence? The number of fields can by any

Comment: @William_Wilson no, set of fields is absolutely free

Comment: That reduced the number of indexing tricks you can apply. Because objects are passed by reference in JavaScript you could create arrays for each of the 4 attributes while looping over the data once. When searching the data you would then need to find an intersect of items which appear in each indexed list. Unfortunately you are looking at O(n) to index the data before you've even done a single search... Is there a reason this must be done in memory? Is the indexed output saved somewhere or will this indexing need to be done each time the page loads?

Comment: @poporul no it is not a must all values to be present - indexing is a kind of classifying. which are present you can classify as i (actually, not me, maths principles :) ) said, also which fields are empty, you can classify them with the very same method. 

A  -> (A_all_attrs_present, A_some_attrs_missing) -> ((A_acc_to_some_property_group_1, A_acc_to_some_property_group_2, .. A_acc_to_some_property_group_n), (A_acc_to_some_property_group_with_missing_values_1, A_acc_to_some_property_group_with_missing_values_2, ... A_acc_to_some_property_group_üith_missing_values_ 3,))

Comment: What are your performance goals? Note: "as fast as possible" doesn't count. 10,000 is a reasonably small number. Perhaps you should implement the brute force search and see if that meets your performance goals. If it does, don't waste time trying to optimize it. The brute force sequential search is easy to code and prove correct. You can use that to verify the correctness of any more advanced algorithm you write.

Answer (score 1):

Because *Type* and *Status* have only ~5 unique values each, searching on one of them (even when indexed) will only cut down your search to 1/5 of ~10000 (~=2000). In your search algorithm I would prioritize your *dateTo* and *dateFrom* since you can search for a unique date using binary search Log_2 of ~10000 (~=13).

For your indexes:

- A sorted by *dateFrom* list of tuples
- A sorted by *dateTo* list of tuples
- A Set for each of your unique *Type* and *Status*
- Since unique *Type* and *Status* are so small you may want to also have a Set for each unique combinaton of *Type* and *Status* (~=25), so that searches that involve both fields will be accelerated as well.

**EDIT** For date range searches (with 2 fields) the best you can do is pick the date index with the least results and filter those for the second date, Log N + Log N + N time.

```
Index1 = BSFirst(dateFromTuples, fromVal)
Index2 = BSLast(dateToTuples, toVal)
If Index1 = 0 AndAlso Index2 = (N - 1) Then
    Result = AllObjects
Else If (N - 1) - Index1 < Index2 Then 
    Result = Filter(dateFromTuples, Index1, n - 1, obj => obj.dateTo <= toVal) 
Else 
    Result = Filter(dateToTuples, 0, Index2, obj => obj.dateFrom >= fromVal)
```

Comment: Note if there is presence **dateFrom** and **dateTo** I want to grab all entries between range

Comment: @poporul - binary search can be modified to get the first or last matching element, so your date range query would be like Union ( BinaySearchFirst(dateFromTuples, fromValue), BinarySearchLast(dateToTuples, toValue) )

Comment: good idea, but what is the worst time complexity of union operation? Isn't ~2N?

Comment: @poporul - It is 2N, so you'd probably want to run both binary searches and pick the one with the least results to do a linear filter on. I've added the pseudo code to my answer. This would be Log N + Log N + N worst case time, which is N. In this case if the date range is foolishly large and you have another search field like *Type* or *Status* then picking that index and doing a linear filter operation may prove optimal.